# CodeIgniter 404 Not Found, как решить проблему

Tags: http-status-code-404, фреймворк, php, php-frameworks, codeigniter

Начал изучать фреймворк Codeigniter и столкнулся с проблемой, нужна помощь.

При переходе по адресу: **http://localhost/newproject/index.php** всё работает, но если пытаюсь добавить к нему контроллер /pages, то выдает ошибку 404 Not Found.

Вот контроллер:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
        public function index() {
            print "hello";
        }
}
```

Не находит адрес:

**http://localhost/newproject/index.php/pages**  и

**http://localhost/newproject/index.php/pages/index**

С чем это может быть связано? Проверил на хостинге, работает, а вот на локальном сервере нет.

Я так понял связано с настройками веб-сервера, я использую nginx. Пытался настроить rewrite, но безуспешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает .htaccess.
Вот неплохой мануал:
http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=apache&page=011

Comment: Я так понял, .htaccess ковырять бесполезно, если веб-сервер nginx, нужно как-то правильно прописать реврайты?

Comment: Тут вам не подскажу, пользуюсь Apache.

Comment: Кажется, разобрался, в конфиге nginx дописал - и заработало:

    location /newproject/ {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /newproject/index.php?$uri&$args;
 index index.php index.html;
    }